# Prove that there is $b$ in $G$ for any $a$ in $G$ such that $a=b^n$ if $(n, |a|)=1$

Tags: group-theory

I was trying to solve a question after Lagrange's Theorem in group theory.

The question is:

Suppose an element $a \in G$ has order $|m|$. For any integer $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, if $(n, m) = 1$, prove that there must exist $b \in G$ such that $a = b^n$.

My try is, since $(n, m) = 1$, there exists integers $x, y$ such that $xn + ym = 1$. Then, we obtain

$$a = a^{xn + ym} = a^{xn}a^{ym}$$

Since $a^m = e (identity)$, $a^{ym} = e$.

Therefore, we have
$$a = a^{xn} = (a^x)^n$$.

Let $b = a^x \in G$, we have $b^n = a$ which completes the proof.

My question is, I couldn't see why this question follows Lagrange's Theorem. I didn't see the reason for applying Lagrange's Theorem to prove it, so I doubt my proof is false.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Your solution is right and does not depend on Lagrange's Theorem. The statement and proof even hold for infinite groups $G$. +1 from me!

Comment: Perhaps this is a misunderstanding. Even if there is an argument using Lagrange it is not necessary to use it. Why do you think you have to use Lagrange? Just because the question came after Lagrange?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is absolutely fine. If you don't want to use Bézout's theorem and use Lagrange instead, you could go for the following solution:

Look at $H:=\langle a\rangle$, which is a group of order $m$. Now look at the group morphism $\varphi:H\to H$ given by $a\mapsto a^n$. The kernel of that morphism are all elements satisfying $x^n=e$. By Lagrange's theorem, any such $x\in Ker (\varphi)$ generate subgroups of $H$ of order dividing $n$ and $m$, thus any $x\in Ker (\varphi)$ is equal to the group's identity element. Thus the kernel of $\varphi$ is trivial and $\varphi$ is an automorphism. Hence there is some element $b\in H$ satisfying $\varphi(b)=b^n=a$.